# sending email with excel files created in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is it possible to send a pandas dataframe through an email in excel format?

I'm trying to avoid having to create the excel sheet, place it physically, and then have to read it back in and send it.

I went out on a limb and tried

```
emxl = df1.to_excel()
```

but since `to_excel` is meant to go to a path, that didn't work. `xlwt` appears to have the same problem.

Is there a possible way to do this without having to create the file outside of python?

Comment: Did you try using [StringIO (or cStringIO)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to create an in-memory file object)?

Comment: That didn't look like it would work with a dataframe. I'll look into that more.

Comment: StringIO should create an object that behaves like a normal file object as far as any interactions are concerned, allowing the usual read and write operations regardless of data being written - I've used it for writing and reading images in the past.